# Multivariate expansion in terms of single variate products: what is the name for this?

Tags: gm.general-mathematics

In some situations we have access to a representation like this:

$ f(x,y) = \sum_i u_i(x) v_i(y) $

What is this called? (I know when you jam this into PDE get to call it 'separation of variables' but I'm sure it's got a different name in pure math).

Comment: The function $f$ is called separable in some other circumstances too.  Like my masters thesis and a number of game theory references therein (none of which have anything to do with PDE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This paper](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2688535?uid=3737536&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21101713553267) calls it "separable of rank $n$" if $n$ is the number of terms in the sum.  If the sum is an infinite one, the condition is very weak (for example it includes all functions with a convergent Taylor expansion).